# Restore site collection in SharePoint online give error

Tags: sharepoint-online, restore

I want to restore a root site collection from recycle bin in SharePoint online it give bellow error:

I tried using SharePoint online management shell bellow command

```
 Restore-SPODeletedSite -Identity https://TheSiteName.sharepoint.com/
```

I tried using the interface it also did not worked and give bellow error:

```
Sorry, something went wrong
There is no site in the current site subscription matching the HiddenSiteSelection control's value.
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried from SharePoint admin center ( from deleted sites)? make sure deleted site is there then try to restore from it.

But if you still getting the error, i would not waste time and open the service request ticket.

Comment: Yes I tried it did not worked, I found a solution which I had to unsubscribe and recreate my tenant from scratch. as there was no other options